# RASA custom action not working with slots though custom action is being executed

Tags: python-3.x, spacy, rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-core

I'm trying to get the current temperature using api, and passing the location slot. I've used only spacy pipeline. I can see from the actions CLI that the custom action is being executed, and fetches the temperature which I've printed. Then why this error?

Config.yml

```
pipeline:
- name: "SpacyNLP" # Language model
- name: "SpacyTokenizer" # Tokenizer
- name: "SpacyFeaturizer" # Featurizer
- name: "SpacyEntityExtractor" #Entity Extractor
- name: "EntitySynonymMapper" # Maps synonymous entity values to the same value.
- name: "SklearnIntentClassifier" # Sklearn intent classifier
```

nlu.yml

```
- intent: get_weather
  examples: |
    - what's the weather in [Kolkata](GPE)
    - what's the weather in [Mumbai](GPE)
    - what is the weather in [Delhi](GPE)
    - what is the weather in [Kolkata](GPE)
    - whats the weather in [Kolkata](GPE)
    - whats the weather in [Delhi](GPE)
```

stories.yml

```
- story: weather path
  steps:
    - intent: get_weather
    - action: action_weather
```

domain.yml

```
slots: 
  PERSON: 
    type: text
  GPE:
    type: text

entities:
  - PERSON
  - GPE

intents:
  - greeting
  - how_are_you
  - bye
  - my_name_is
  - get_weather

actions: # actions define the responses of your bot. 
  - utter_greeting # Simple text response names start with utter_.
  - utter_how_i_am
  - utter_bye
  - utter_its_nice_to_meet_you
  - action_weather

responses:  
  utter_greeting: 
    - text: "Hi! Could you please help me with your name?"
    - text: "Hello, my friend. What can I call you?"
  utter_how_i_am:
    - text: "I am doing ok."
    - text: "I am good."
  utter_bye:
    - text: "Bye."
    - text: "Good bye."
  utter_its_nice_to_meet_you:
    - text: "It's nice to meet you, {PERSON}."
    - text: "Nice to meet you, {PERSON}."
```

actions.py

```
from typing import Any, Text, Dict, List
from rasa_sdk import Action, Tracker
from rasa_sdk.executor import CollectingDispatcher
import requests

class ActionGetWeather(Action):
     def name(self):
          return "action_weather"
     def run(self, dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher,
            tracker: Tracker,
            domain: Dict[Text, Any]) -> List[Dict[Text, Any]]:

        location = tracker.get_slot("GPE")
        #person = tracker.get_slot("PERSON")
        
        params = {"appid": "xxxxxxxx" , 'q': location, "units": "metric"}
        response = requests.get("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather",params = params).json()
        temp = str(response['main']['temp'])
        print(temp)
        dispatcher.utter_message(temp)

        return []
```

Error screenshot attached

[image]